# Adding a folder to side panel nautilus NOT as a bookmark on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, directory

Everything here is only about **Nautilus** and adding a folder to the left panel.

Recently due to insufficient space in the home partition, I had to remove the downloads folder through the recovery method. But after reboot, the **Downloads** folder shortcut did not appear in the left panel in Nautilus.

Is there any way to add the **Downloads** folder shortcut back into place?

**Not as a bookmark**.

Currently, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver).

[image: Nautilus, with no Downloads link in left panel]

Comment: Today I've pointed out that the Downloads folder is back when I tried to change the language from English to another language with the error stating "Changing language has to translate the directory from home\toor to home\toor\Downloads" while translating it didn't find the downloads folder. It has created the directory.

Comment: But even my primary question didn't get resolved which is how to add a folder into the panel, help me with it. I Think the above comment could help someone who mistakenly deleted the Downloads folder and trying to get it back. It was really simple and Unexpected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using Fedora 31 and had the same issue inside nautilus.
There is a config file for every user that contains some path for the standard directories such as Downloads, Documents, ...
Default content must be like this:

```
$ cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs

# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run.
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

I guess your default paths for missing items in panel had changed to something else like "$HOME".

You can edit this file manually and point to correct path. But most likely there is a command like `xdg-user-dirs-update` available in your shell just for this purpose. Rename or remove the config file and run the command to make a new config file with default values.

```
mv ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs.broken
xdg-user-dirs-update
```

Any changes takes effect after logout and login.

For more details see this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167833/340334
and this article https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_user_directories

Answer (score 0):

Open a session as user with sudo rights; create an other user (I name mine `test`)

```
    sudo adduser test
```

Open a session as user `test`. This will create directories in `/home/test`. Among those directories there is a `Downloads` directory (if your locales are `en`, for me `Téléchargements` because `fr` locales). End this `test` session.

Reopen session with sudo rights, copy `/home/test/Downloads` to your home directory, and chown the copy to you and your_group.

I think it can be done but I don't master bash so I go to `/home/test` with Nautilus, open a terminal, launch `midnight commander`

```
    sudo mc
```

and use it to copy `Downloads` (listed left under `/home/test/` ) to listed right `/home/my_personal_folder/`; then hightlight the copied `Downloads` (listed right)
and action `Files/Chown` menu to me and my_group.

This works on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 upgrade  over 16.04.

I wonder why creating a simple `Downloads` directory doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I've solved the question for creating the Downloads _but not for adding any folder_ into the panel.

Comment: `man xdg-user-dirs-update` shows that some bookmarks are translations.

Comment: `cat ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` shows that Documents, Downloads, etc.
are bookmarks highlighted with specific icons.