# "Downloads" folder shortcut on the left pane of nautilus disappeared; how do I get it back?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, shortcuts, symbolic-link

["Downloads" folder shortcut disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTeEq.png)

The **Downloads** folder shortcut on the left pane of nautilus has disappeared. How do I get it back?

Today, I opened the terminator and removed the "Downloads" folder. Then I linked it to a folder on another disk.

```
rm -r Downloads
ln -s '/media/my_name/my_disk/dl' Downloads
```

I did the same to the **Pictures** folder and it looks fine. But I lost my **Downloads** folder shortcut on the left pane of nautilus (file browser).

I tried to revert this change. So I removed the link and recreated the **Downloads** folder, but the shortcut didn't come back. What should I do?

I use Ubuntu 20.04, Unity Desktop, Nautilus (3.36.2-0ubuntu1).

Comment: Solved according to https://askubuntu.com/a/1184296/1082503

Comment: It should be a bug. "Downloads" folder disappears once and once again.